# My custom devise views aren't displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, view

I created the `/views/user/` folder using `rails g devise:views` but devise is still using the default views somehow.

Am I missing a configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, read documentation and add to your `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

Also see that `rails g devise:views` create `app/views/devise` containing all needed views. If you don't have many Devise Models in your app **DO NOT** use above solution but simply edit files in `app/views/devise`. Then it will work faster, because it don't need to look every time for specified views.